# First column fixed in mat-table

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

do you happen to know how to fix the first column and use horizontal scrolling in mat-table in Angular Material?

I would be very grateful for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You should use `mat-table` API for this - `sticky` value.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Please check in official doc:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples
example name: "Table with a sticky columns"

Comment: plus second flag stickyEnd for column at the end of the row

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to you component, let's call it `isSticky(column)`. Then bind `[sticky]` to it. See below for the entire working example link.

**HTML**

```
<div class="app-table-wrapper">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" id="app-table">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" matColumnDef={{column}} [sticky]="isSticky(column)">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[column]}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>S
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
isSticky (column: string): boolean {
  return column === 'col1' ? true : false;
}
```

**Full Example**

[StackBlitz - angular-sticky-table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sticky-table)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the solution I needed. Many months later, I used this function during development and I am satisfied.

Comment: How can I fix multiple columns using isSticky? Only one column can be frozen with the return. I tried it with an array, but it did not work... Do you have an idea?